# Configure reverse proxy in NGINX for OData requests

Tags: nginx, odata, sapui5

I have been following the nginx documentation in https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/ to set a reverse proxy for my OData requests, but there must be something I'm doing wrong because I keep getting 404 errors.

My nginx.conf looks like this:

```
location / {
            root   /Users/me/Sites;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            autoindex on;
}

location /sap/opu/odata {
            proxy_pass http://server_machine:XXXX/sap/opu/odata;
            proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic myEncodedPassword";
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This config did it for me:

```
   server {
    charset UTF-8;
    listen XXXX;
    root /html;
    index index.html;
    server_name YYYYY;

 location /resources {
        alias "C:\\XXXXX";
    }

     location / {
        alias "C:\\XXXXX";
    }

location /sap {
            proxy_pass http://XXX.XX.XX.XXX/sap;
            proxy_set_header        Accept-Encoding   "";
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
            deny all;
    }
```

}